# how to send multiple attachment in 1 email using uuencode

Tags: debian, email

I have a problem. I need to write a script that will find any file generated 1 day ago And then email it to certain mail-address from Tuesday to Sunday at 2 am?

The problem is my script finds the 3 correct files but either sends 3 different emails with single attachment or send 1 email without any attachment. How can I edit it to send multiple attachments in 1 email? It seems every file needs a 'uuencode' with it, so tried concating "uuencode" to the "filename" 
and then add that variable to the command of ssmpt. Neither of the 2 version are really working.

How can I write the regular experession so that all the files found is emailed using 1 email. My current script just sends email with no attachment at all or 1 file per email.

Please help.

Here is what my script looks like:

***Version 1: sends 1 email with no attachment:***

```
#!/bin/bash
dt=$(date --date yesterday "+%Y-%m-%d")
result="performance-team*-$dt.txt"

arr=()
arr=($(find /root/Desktop/fileNAme -type f -name "${result}"))


for i in "${arr[@]}"
do 
    value=" uuencode -e $i $(basename $i);"
    valueTotal=$valueTotal$value;
done

echo -e "to:email@email.com\nSubject:performance of teams on ${dt};"|(cat - && ${valueTotal};)|/usr/sbin/ssmtp email@email.com
```

***Version 2: sends 3 email with single attachment in each:***

```
#!/bin/bash
dt=$(date --date yesterday "+%Y-%m-%d")
result="performance-team*-$dt.txt"

arr=()
arr=($(find /root/Desktop/fileNAme -type f -name "${result}"))

Count=0
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do 
    Count=$((Count+1))
    echo -e "to:email@email.com\nSubject:performance of teams on ${dt}; mail    ${Count} of 3\n"|(cat - && uuencode $i;)|/usr/sbin/ssmtp to:email@email.com
done
```

Comment: How about using `tar` to combine the files you find, and then `uuencode` the resulting tarfile?

Comment: Or is `mutt` available?

Answer (score 1):

`uuencode` is the wrong tool for the job. (It was the right tool about 25 years ago, though, but has long been superseded by the MIME standard.)

On my Debian distribution a script can use the `mail` command directly. The man page for `mail` says, amongst other things, "***-a file** Attach the given file to the message*". Here is an example that sends three attachments encoded using MIME.

```
echo 'Here is my email' |
    mail -s 'Test message' -a /etc/hosts -a /etc/group -a /etc/motd bill@contoso.com
```

I have not had time to check this next part, but it looks like [`munpack`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/munpack.1.html) may be the tool to perform the reverse conversion, i.e. extract MIME attachments from an email back into files.