# What are some better options for encoding email attachments than uuencode in a bash script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, email, character-encoding

I'm referencing [my original post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378022/in-a-bash-shell-script-can-2-equal-multiple-arguments-on-the-command-line-or-do?) in which I was asking a question about argument placement pertaining to `$2 $3` etc, and eventually `${@:2}`. It was mentioned that there are better methods to encode email attachments.

Note, I used `uname -or` to figure out `2.6.32-400.26.3.el5uek GNU/Linux`.

I used the command within a bash script to attach a file to an email, and have it in a couple other scripts as well.  However, a few of our machines do not even support `uuencode`, so what are some better options for attaching files to emails than uuencode?

Comment: MIME (base64) encoding is used for this purpose.

Comment: Your implementation of `mail` may include `-a` to attach a file, in which case the encoding is handled under the hood for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send multiple attachment in 1 email using uuencode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317285/how-to-send-multiple-attachment-in-1-email-using-uuencode), which actually offers a MIME-based alternative to `uuencode`.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using mpack to send attachments as MIME

as in:

```
mpack -s "message" file email@example.com
```

> Name
>
> mpack - pack a file in MIME format Synopsis
>
> mpack [ -s subject ] [ -d descriptionfile ] [ -m maxsize ] [ -c
>   content-type ] file address ... mpack [ -s subject ] [ -d
>   descriptionfile ] [ -m maxsize ] [ -c content-type ] -o outputfile
>   file mpack [ -s subject ] [ -d descriptionfile ] [ -m maxsize ] [ -c
>   content-type ] -n newsgroups file Description
>
> The mpack program encodes the the named file in one or more MIME
>   messages. The resulting messages are mailed to one or more recipients,
>   written to a named file or set of files, or posted to a set of
>   newsgroups.

Answer (score 1):

You know I find that the following works just fine for files in either TEXT or binary:

```
 mailx -s SUBJECT -a FILE1 -a FILE2 ... USERNAME
```

It basically does the MIME encoding automatically and.....even M$ Outlook does the right thing with such a message.

Answer (score 0):

If missing `uuencode`, this `perl` hack does pretty much the same thing.

Credit goes to [Perl Monks site](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=320847)

```
perl -ple"BEGIN{ $/=\45} $_ = pack 'u', $_" file
```

Comment: The question is about avoiding use of `uuencode`. The back-story is that a MIME-compliant solution is being sought.

Answer (score 0):

You could 7z or zip or tar.wz or similar to get a compressed list of files.

Then the compressed list of files could be converted to hex. Use od hd or xxd:

```
$ xxd -p compressedfile.7z > ToBeMailedFile
```

Send the file attached to your email.

Convert back the file:

```
$ xxd -p -r ToBeMailedFile > compressedfile.7z
```

Expand the file to the list of files.

As HEX pass every web limitation of characters allowed, the file will pass.
As the list of files is compressed before being sent, there is a gain of size.
The compressed file could be also encrypted.
Several diferent tools could be used to process the data. Only the conversion of HEX to BIN needs xxd. So, freedom of tools.

Comment: `xxd` is less efficient; it requires 103% more space than the input, *vs* only 37% more for `uuencode` and 35% for *base64*.  Demo:  `i=/bin/dash o=/dev/stdout ; wc -c $i <(uuencode $i $o) <(uuencode -m $i $o) <(xxd -p $i) | head -n -1`

Comment: @agc You may be correct; however: The question specified that `uuencode` was not available: *better options for attaching files to emails than uuencode?*