# Having problem using uuencode in script

Tags: shell-script, ksh, mailx

I am using below command and it works:

```
uuencode stats.txt stats.txt | mailx -s "users" info@whale.de
```

But when I put same command inside my shell script, it does not work.

I dont have email. I am using `ksh`. Can anyone tell me why it fails?

Solution:
There was no error and no email sent either.
When I used set -x for debug nothing was returned either for debug.

I moved the uuencode section out the function section in the script to a separate section. And it worked; the debug returned message and I got email

Comment: Hi Drsin, it will be helpful if you post the error-messages your script prints.  You can `set -x` in the first line of your script to help with debugging.

Comment: Thanks @markgraf. I removed the uuencode from the function within the script. It works now within its own section inside same script.  The set -x was helpful to debug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to send multiple attachment in 1 email using uuencode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317285/how-to-send-multiple-attachment-in-1-email-using-uuencode)

Comment: @roaima It would still be somewhat interesting to understand why it worked standalone on the command-line though ...

Comment: @AdminBee having used `uuencode` myself in years gone by (doesn't that make me feel old!) I can't see anything wrong with the single line snippet posted here. We'd need to see permissions on `stats.txt` and have an explanation of "_it does not work_" - for example, does `uuencode` not produce output, or does the `mailx` generate an error, or ...?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the previous errors.  And then answer your question with how you fixed it.  Don't be DenverCoder9, please, that's a very bad habit.  See https://xkcd.com/979/